# Rails + Whenever: run tasks with same schedule in different days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I'm using whenever gem to run schedule jobs.
My schedule.rb has something like this:

```
every 3.days, :at => '2:10 pm' do
   runner "Something.task()"
end

every 3.days, :at => '1:10 pm' do
   runner "Something.othertask()"
end
```

The thing is, is it possible to define that the first job starts to run today and other, only tomorrow? So they will never run at the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw cron syntax as well if you cant figure out how to use with ruby syntax.

What you want will look like:

```
every '0 2 20 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron sytax too'"
end
```

Here is a quick cheatseet for how to use cron syntax

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

from: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Comment: I'm doing this right now while I can't find out how (and if it's possible) to do using that syntax. Thanks!